# How to show approved comments in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show post's comments (`approved = true`) We have a single post with a random slug/id, But the problem is: How can I show approved comments with that specific post id !?

I think i have to use something like this following example :

```
Post::find($id)->Comments()->whereApproved(true)->get()
```

Comments Table :

[image]

Comment: what is relation between post and comments , put your model relation in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from the description, `approved` column is in the `comments` table. You can get comments with just one query since you know post ID:

```
Comment::where('post_id', $postId)
       ->where('approved', true)
       ->get();
```

If you want to get the post with approved comments, do this:

```
Post::with(['comments' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('approved', true);
}])->find($postId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If approved is a column in comments table you should use this :

```
Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', true);
}])->get();
```

This code returns all posts with approved comments

So you can use it in your blade

```
$post->Comments
```

Don't forget to use `foreach` or looping

Answer (score 0):

$comments = Comments::where('comments',1)->get();
**here 1 is your approved comments**